# Authentication issue VBA Excel

Tags: excel, jira, basic-authentication, jira-rest-api

I am trying to create a cookie / authenticate my user name and password against JIRA API. It does not work as I am getting login denied. This is the code that I am using :

```
Set JiraAuth = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")

With JiraAuth
    .Open "POST", "http://website/rest/auth/1/session", False
    .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    .Send " {""username"" : ""USER"", ""password"" : ""USERPASSWORD!""}"""
    sErg = .ResponseText
    sCookie = "JSESSIONID=" & Mid(sErg, 42, 32) & "; Path=/Jira"  '*** Extract the Session-ID
End With
```

This is the response that I am receiving:

> :{"errorMessages":["Login denied"],"errors":{}}
>   ,"errors":{}}

If I use IE browser I can login with the username and password that I give. So the login credentials are not the issue.

Do I need to encrypt the password?
How can I resolve this / any examples that I could look at?

Comment: This works fine for me. The only change I made was to switch to https since our Jira server doesn't redirect http to 443.

Comment: What happens if you try basic auth over the URL like: `http://USER:USERPASSWORD@website/rest/auth/1/session` do you get the same error?

Comment: I have not tried that yet will give it a go and reply back. I am unable to use https . If you access the url directly what json message do you get back ?

Comment: If you hit that exact URL you should get information about your own sessions like failedLoginCount, loginCount, lastFailedLoginTime, previousLoginTime in JSON format. I should have added, try that directly in the browser and see what happens. It should be the same as going through the MSXML2 object, but then you can rule out fat fingering of code if you get a login error.

Comment: If i try that via internet explorer browser i get 'windows cannot find : webaddress' . If i try it via google chrome, after clearing my history and cache i get "{"errorMessages": ["You are not authenticated. Authentication required to perform this operation."],"errors": {}} ". If i hit the URL again in chrome the correct page json page appears. I guess the reason it works the second time is because it is using my windows login. Still no closer in finding out this issue. Any other ideas that i could try?